# Is a letter from a non-US licensed physician legally valid to use prescription tint windows in California?

Tags: united-states, california, international, health

I read in the [California Assembly Bill no. 1303 (September 2017) – amended medical exemptions](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billTextClient.xhtml?bill_id=201720180AB1303):

> (10) Sun screening devices meeting the requirements of Section 26708.2 installed on the side windows on either side of the vehicle’s front seat, if the driver or a passenger in the front seat has in his or her possession **a letter or other document signed by a licensed physician and surgeon certifying that the person must be shaded from the sun due to a medical condition**, or has in his or her possession a letter or other document signed by a licensed optometrist certifying that the person must be shaded from the sun due to a visual condition. The devices authorized by this paragraph shall not be used during darkness.

and:

> (e) Notwithstanding subdivision (a), clear, colorless, and transparent material may be installed, affixed, or applied to the windshield, side, or rear windows of a motor vehicle if the following conditions are met:
>   (1) The material has a minimum visible light transmittance of 88 percent.
>   (2) The window glazing with the material applied meets all requirements of Federal Motor Vehicle Safety Standard No. 205 (49 C.F.R. 571.205), including the specified minimum light transmittance of 70 percent and the abrasion resistance of AS–14 glazing, as specified in that federal standard.
>   (3) The material is designed and manufactured to enhance the ability of the existing window glass to block the sun’s harmful ultraviolet A rays.
>   (4) The driver has in his or her possession, or within the vehicle, a certificate signed by a **licensed dermatologist** certifying that the person should not be exposed to ultraviolet rays because of a medical condition that necessitates clear, colorless, and transparent film material to be installed on the windshield, side, or rear windows.
>   (5) If the material described in this subdivision tears or bubbles, or is otherwise worn to prohibit clear vision, it shall be removed or replaced.

Is a letter from a non-US (United States) licensed physician legally valid to use prescription tint windows in California?

Comment: Good question. I don't know the answer.

Comment: How does one un-tint the windows for "The devices authorized by this paragraph shall not be used during darkness."

Comment: @fred_dot_u: Given that they're on side windows, presumably by rolling down the window. It's California, not Alaska.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Good point, I am now confused: [Does California allows prescription tint windows?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/49495/31)

Comment: @fred_dot_u It seems that I was reading the wrong portion of the bill (thanks [Nate Eldredge](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/576/nate-eldredge) for pointing me to the correct portion), please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You should simplify your question to:

- Under California law, what is considered to be a **licensed physician**?

Based on the summary below, where the following can be found:

> The California Licensure Statute does not allow for license reciprocity between states.

you can assume that a **non-US (United States) licensed physician** is also not allowed since the terminology **in another state *or country*** is used in the California **Business and Professions Code**.

---

> **Executive Summary**
>   **California Licensure Physician Statute**
>   **Licensure Requirements**: Those wishing to practice medicine in the state of California need to obtain a full medical license. California does not have specific language within its state statute, nor its administrative regulations, granting physicians a “special/limited” license to enter the state remotely to practice telemedicine.
>
> **Licensure Reciprocity**: The California Licensure Statute does not allow for license reciprocity between states.
>
> **Licensure Exceptions**: The California Licensure Statute allows for the following common exceptions:
>
> - Consultative Services: Physicians are able to offer consultative services without being required to receive full medical licensure.
> - Military Exception: Those physicians, licensed in any one of the 50 states, are permitted to administer care to military members, as either a civilian contract employee or a military physician officer, without having to first receive additional licensure.
> - Emergency Exception: A physician is permitted to administer care to a person in an emergency situation, regardless if that physician is licensed in the state where the care is taking place.
> - Medical Students Exception: A medical student may administer care to a patient under the advisement of a physician licensed in California.
>
> **Internet Prescribing of Medication**: The California Licensure Statute does not allow for the administration of medication over the internet without a prior physical medical examination.
>   ...
>   **Business and Professions Code § 2076**.
>
> (a) Notwithstanding any other provision of law, a physician and surgeon **who is licensed to practice medicine in another state or country** ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Executive Summary California Licensure Physician Statute Licensure Requirements: Those wishing ... - Center for Telehealth and e-Health Law](http://www.ctel.org/annotated_states/California_Annotated__%2520(2579579_1).PDF) (PDF)