# Does California allow prescription window tints?

Tags: united-states, california, driving

Prescription window tints = window tints that are darker than typically allowed due to a medical reason.

---

I read in the [California Assembly Bill no. 1303 (September 2017) – amended medical exemptions](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billTextClient.xhtml?bill_id=201720180AB1303):

> (10) Sun screening devices meeting the requirements of Section 26708.2 installed on the side windows on either side of the vehicle’s front seat, if the driver or a passenger in the front seat has in his or her possession **a letter or other document signed by a licensed physician and surgeon certifying that the person must be shaded from the sun due to a medical condition**, or has in his or her possession a letter or other document signed by a licensed optometrist certifying that the person must be shaded from the sun due to a visual condition. **The devices authorized by this paragraph shall not be used during darkness**.

Does that mean that in practice California doesn't allow prescription window tints, since (to my knowledge) there is no way to remove window tint every night?

That's my understanding from the quoted text, however I see on Google many websites claiming that California allows prescription tint windows, and as a result I wonder whether I am looking at the correct text of law.

For example https://www.abc10.com/article/news/local/california/new-california-law-allows-for-additional-window-tinting/470732486 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200228000627/https://www.abc10.com/article/news/local/california/new-california-law-allows-for-additional-window-tinting/470732486)) says:

> If you've got a doctor's note, you will able to get additional window tints on your car.
>
> Gov. Jerry Brown signed **Assembly Bill 1303 into law Friday, which allows window tinting on the windshield, side or rear windows of a car if a licensed dermatologist certifies** that a person should not be exposed to UV rays because of a medical condition.
>
> With a signed dermatologist note, a person can now install window tinting with a lower light transmittance rating than currently allowed on a vehicle, according to state Assembly floor analysis of the law.
>
> Medical conditions such as Lupus can make UV light sensitive. Exposure can cause an immune system attack.
>
> Copyright 2017 KXTV

Comment: It looks to me like the ABC10 story is referring to subsection (e) of the law, not (b)(10) which you are reading.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you, good catch, in that case my understanding  subsection (e) is that in California having a prescription or medical note does not allow to have window tints that are different than non-prescription window tints, since both non-prescription window tints and [non-prescription window tints must have a minimum light transmittance of 70 percent](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&division=12.&title=&part=&chapter=4.&article=). Do you agree?

Comment: I am not sure, and don't really want to spend more time looking into it.  Sorry.

Comment: @NateEldredge no worries, reading legal texts is indeed a time sink.  Thanks for your help earlier to point to the right passage in the text!